# Extended association plots in R

Tags: r, associations

I am having trouble creating an extended association plot in R that shows there is a relationship between two variables. I'm using the assoc() function in the vcd package, using Rstudio (Version 0.97.551) through R (Version 3.0.1) on a Mac OS X 10.6.

My data is a 6x3 array with row and column names:

```
    names<-c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
    y<-c(340, 37, 110, 17, 71)
    z<-c(720, 14, 6, 141, 120)
    x<-data.frame(names, y, z); x
```

The code I'm using is:

```
    x <- read.table(file.choose(), header=TRUE, row.names=1, sep="\t", comment.char=""); x # Load x.txt
    attach(x)
    x.m <- as.matrix(x[,]); x.m
    library(vcd)
    assocplot(t(x.m)) # Output regular association plot (residuals not shown) = normal plot.
    assoc(t(x.m)) # Output extended association plot with Pearson's residuals = error plot.
```

The regular assocplot() function calls a normal plot, with the associations in red and black tiles. The assoc() function is calling an error plot that is just a bunch of letters centred on a very small location in the middle of the plot, with "A" and "B" labels on the x and y axis.

I have previously outputted an extended association plot with this data successfully, but as a relatively inexperienced R user, I'm not exactly sure what the problem is now. I've tried various means of troubleshooting, including running the code in regular R as well as Rstudio (the problem persists), and many different forum searches. I also asked another user to try the code above using my array, and they successfully outputted an extended association plot on their machine.

If anyone is able to help, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: After tests with other users who replicated the problem, I contacted the vcd authors and they confirmed there is a bug, which will be fixed in the next vcd update. I also managed to output an extended association plot successfully after installing an earlier version of R (2.14.0).

Answer (score 0):

I checked on this a month or two ago with the person at the R project who is the package maintainer.  This issue arose with R version 3.0.  You'll note that the examples provided in the assoc function documentation also produce this behavior.  Doesn't seem to be fixed, so far, at least not as of today.